# How to search for document by id in Mongo Explorer plugin of php storm

Tags: php, mongodb, phpstorm, robo3t

I use both [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) and [rockmongo](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo) as clients for mongo dbs.. suppose I got a collection called *Drivers*, then searching by id is quite easy:

```
db.Driver.find({_id:ObjectId('51118447b38639a960000002')})
```

I recently installed a [mongo plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7141?pr=dbe) for [Php Storm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), however I couldn't figure out how to search for a document by id.. the above query fails:

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the [support forum](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/28), you should query as:

```
{_id: {$oid: '51118447b38639a960000002'}}
```

Comment: Stunned that this isn't in the guide.  Why isn't _id: ObjectId(' .... ') supported

Answer (score 3):

```
{"_id":ObjectId("51118447b38639a960000002")}
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Using `$oid` no longer works, at least not in DataGrip